# reading while open/writing to file in .net?

Tags: .net, file-io

I notice many applications like firefox allow me to watch part of a video (using VLC) when the file is still downloading. I would like to do that with my application. When i tried opening the video with VLC i get an error.

How do i allow reading when i write to a file? my open line is

```
File.Open(fn, FileMode.Append)
```

i do append so i can resume partial files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the [Open overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725.aspx), that takes a [FileShare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) parameter:

```
File.Open(fn, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)
```

This way you explicitly state that other processes are allowed to open the file for reading while you are still writing to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are leaving it up to the Open() method to pick the FileShare value passed to the FileStream constructor.  Which is FileShare.None.  Specify your own.